# Specifying both IPv4 and IPv6 IP types in akamai.EdgeHostName

Tags: akamai, pulumi

Pulumi recently updated their Akamai package. There's a new property when creating an EdgeHostName resource called **ipBehavior**. What do I put as the value for this property when I need the EdgeHostName IP Type to be `IPv4 + IPv6`? I've attached a screenshot of the desired IP type on the Akamai Property Manager Editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the possible values are `IPV4` for version 4 only, `IPV6_PERFORMANCE` for version 6 only, or `IPV6_COMPLIANCE` for both 4 and 6.